# Tap gesture has nil value

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add TapGuesture in `viewForHeaderInSection` of UITableView. Below is the code in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if !isFromSearchBarData {
        let headerView = CategoryHeaderView(frame: CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50.0))
        headerView.viewDictModel = arrayOfCategoryDictionary[section].values.first
        headerView.tag = section
        //Add Tap
        let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:#selector(sectionHeaderTapped(tapGesture:)))
        headerTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        headerView .addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)
        return headerView
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now Action is below

```
 @objc func sectionHeaderTapped(tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   //...some code...//

   print("Item is :\(String(describing: tapGesture.view?.tag))")
  //SOme Code on **Tag**....//
  }
```

I can see that app is running fine on Simulator & I can get TapGesture View in action. App also work in iPhone 8 plus with iOS 11.0

but I tried ti run the app on iPhone SE or iPhone 8 having iOS > 11.2, app is crashing because of  'tapGesture.view?.tag' is nil

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe on iPhone SE the list is too big, the footer is reused and so the view is released ?

Comment: what about iPhone 8? And App is working on iPhone SE Simulator.

Comment: I think, the view reference will become nil while scrolling. Create a strong reference for `HeaderView` and then try